# What happened to System.Web.Mvc.dll?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

A colleague emailed me an example ASP.NET MVC project that won't build on my machine as it contains a reference to `System.Web.Mvc.dll`

In the .csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

I have VS2008 SP1 installed and can create new ASP.NET MVC web applications. However these don't include a reference to this assembly.

So, does anyone know in what version(s) of ASP.NET MVC this assembly exists, and what I should do to get this project to build?

### Edit

How can I find out what version of ASP.NET MVC is installed on a machine?

Comment: I believe this was before Beta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MVC just went RTM. You may be running an earlier version. Get the latest one.

[ASP.NET MVC 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en) includes the assembly `System.Web.Mvc.dll`

Answer (score 4):

**To find out what version of MVC is installed:**

Search Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET for System.Web.Mvc.dll.

It should be in a folder that has the release name on it or failing that right click and check the properties.

**To fix your problem:**

1. From within Visual Studio expand the
   references section and delete the
   current reference to System.Web.Mvc (right click "Remove").
2. Right click on References and select
   "Add Reference"
3. Select System.Web.MVC from the .NET
   tab.
4. Rebuild your application.

It should now compile and run.

Comment: "From the .NET tab" ? that doesn't exist

Comment: @sports - you're talking about an answer that's nearly 6 years old. The whole question is probably out of date.

Answer (score 3):

You can also go to: http://www.microsoft.com/web/

And download the Web Platform Installer and install the MVC and other stuff through it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer -

Best way is to use NuGet package manager.
Just update the below MVC package and it should work

[Why is System.Web.Mvc not listed in Add References?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648364/why-is-system-web-mvc-not-listed-in-add-references/23976853#23976853)