# Odata Put endpoint doesn't work as expected on ASP.NET Core MVC web service

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, odata

I recently passed from an Entity Framework app to an Entity Framework Core one, I'm developing an API as a web service.

I have some `GET` endpoints that are working properly, and the put endpoint did work yesterday before to end work with adding `[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPut]` before the endpoint definition instead of `[Microsoft.Http.Mvc.HttpPut]`.

Now it's creating a new entity even if the passed Id exists.

I went above an [interesting link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648364/why-is-system-web-mvc-not-listed-in-add-references) and tried to install `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` as stated in this link, and modified `[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPut]` to `[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPut]` without success. I also tried `[System.Http.Mvc.HttpPut]` with no luck.

Every time I call the PUT endpoint, instead of answering a `204 NO CONTENT` with the updated object, it answers a `201 CREATED`.

I tried with Postman, same result;

The issue is that according to documentation, my Mvc Application should accept `application/json` Content-Type header by default. But even when I try with swagger, the parameters are passed in URL.

Here's my OData `UsersController`:

```
using System.Net;
using SyncSchools.WebServices.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Deltas;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Formatter;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Template;

namespace SyncSchools.WebServices.Controllers.Odata
{
    public class UsersController : ODataController
    {
        SyncSchoolsContext _dbContext = new SyncSchoolsContext();

        //[EnableQuery]
        //public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
        //{
        //    var q = _dbContext.Users.AsQueryable();
        //    return q; 
        //}

        // GET odata/Users
        [EnableQuery]
        [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
        public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
        {
            return _dbContext.Users;
        }

        // GET odata/Users(5)
        [EnableQuery]
        [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
        public Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Results.SingleResult<User> GetUser([FromODataUri] Guid key)
        {
            return Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Results.SingleResult.Create(_dbContext.Users.Where(User => User.Id == key));
        }

        // PUT odata/User(5)
        [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
        [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] Guid key, User User)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return (IActionResult)BadRequest(ModelState);

            return await SaveChanges(User);
        }

        // POST odata/User
        [HttpPost]
        [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(User User)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return (IActionResult)BadRequest(ModelState);

            return await SaveChanges(User);
        }

        private async Task<IActionResult> SaveChanges(User data)
        {
            var existing = _dbContext.Users.Find(data.Id);

            var dbentry = _dbContext.Entry(data);

            if (existing == null)
                _dbContext.Users.Add(data);
            else
                _dbContext.Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(data);

            try
            {
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }

            if (existing == null)
                return (IActionResult)Created(data);
            else
                return (IActionResult)Updated(data);
        }

        // PATCH odata/User(5)
        [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "MERGE")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] Guid key, Delta<User> patch)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return (IActionResult)BadRequest(ModelState);

            User User = await _dbContext.Users.FindAsync(key);

            if (User == null)
                return (IActionResult)NotFound();

            patch.Patch(User);

            try
            {
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!UserExists(key))
                    return (IActionResult)NotFound();
                else
                    throw;
            }

            return (IActionResult)Updated(User);
        }

        // DELETE odata/User(5)
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete([FromODataUri] Guid key)
        {
            User User = await _dbContext.Users.FindAsync(key);

            if (User == null)
                return (IActionResult)NotFound();

            _dbContext.Users.Remove(User);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return (IActionResult)StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        /*protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _dbContext.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }*/

        private bool UserExists(Guid key)
        {
            return _dbContext.Users.Any(e => e.Id == key);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my `Program.cs` with the Cors policy definition:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder => { builder.AllowAnyMethod(); builder.AllowAnyHeader(); builder.AllowAnyOrigin(); }));
    
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
    });
    
var app = builder.Build(); 
        
// Pour permettre les tests en local
app.UseCors();
```

I'm a bit lost here, any help would be welcome.

Comment: Let’s start with some easy questions. When you actually debug the API and look at the SaveChanges function and pass in the data via the PUT call you’re making does the existing always equal null? Also, is that a UID that you’re using for the Find statement and how is that configured at the model class for the User Entity? I feel like the search being performed is not actually returning anything and it’s always thinking it’s null and then creating a new entity but a simple debug should answer a lot of questions.

Comment: Hi ! Yeah the existing is always null when calling with `application/json` as the User is always empty as the Id in the User object received is always 00000-000-000-00000 and yes it's a Uid.
The Id is a Guid on the User Entity as every others entities.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, could you show me an example of what you're passing to the API as a PUT request?

Comment: I solved the issue by the time, I'll answer my own post ;)
Thanks for the help anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue came from multiple causes.

1. I had to add `[FromBody]` to the `User` parameter to specify that I was waiting for JSON Javascript body.
2. The JSON that I was sending was malformed, it was lacking some `User` Class defined attributes. This was causing the request to create an empty `User` cause the `User` parameter wasn't linked to the JSON Body due to missing attributes, and the `Guid` was null in the `User` received by the endpoint, causing the Put endpoint to create another user with a new Guid, returning a `201 CREATED` without raising any error.
3. For information I used `HttpPost` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`, so I don't think the download of Microsoft ASP.NET MVC package changed a thing.

It was still working without defining JsonOptions in the `Program.cs`.

Here's the endpoint definition that works:

```
[HttpPut]
[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] Guid key, [FromBody] User User) {}
```